# How do I pass data to another component using Vue router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Currently, I have a component that is rendered on the page, when I console log the `this.$router` variable inside the component, i see the full path property is equal to '/hello/reports?report=3849534583957' and the path property is equal to just '/hello/reports/'.

In a separate component I am trying to pass data to the component above by using

```
this.$router.push({path:`/hello/reports?report=3849534583957`, params: {data: 'hey'}})`
```

However, when I try to look at the params in the vue devtools or by console logging `this.$route.params.data` it returns me undefined.

I believe I am doing everything correctly, please help me understand where I am going wrong. I have tried replacing the full path property's value with just the regular path property's value, inside the push method as well.  Thank you

Comment: What does your router config look like?

Answer (score 1):

Router params map to values that are setup in the router configuration.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{ path: '/user/:id', component: User }]
})
```

`id` is a valid param for this route.

Find more on the official docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#dynamic-route-matching